# How to use OpenGL 2.0 rather than a later version?

Tags: c++, opengl

The goal is to make a game which will be compatible with many Graphics cards, and cross-platform. I decided to go with OpenGL 2.0 and Glut.

I quickly came to realize however, that there are no specific DLL for version OpenGL version 1.0, 2.0, 2.1... This lead me to wonder, how exactly do you choose which OpenGL version you need?

Also, I am aware that Windows Visual Studio only comes with OpenGL version 1.1. That is why I decided to use Glut, so that I could use functions from a later version of OpenGL such as 2.0.

The question remains, how do I use a certain version of OpenGL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply don't use any of the new features introduced since 2.0

Comment: So if I understand right, I could download the latest OpenGL version, and as long that I don't use newer features than 2.0, then I will be fine. How exactly do I know which functions were provided for version 2.0?

Comment: Correct, Start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#OpenGL_2.0 (there are a few differences between 2.0 and 2.1 - but pretty much all of the common openGL is 2.0)

Comment: @user42282: You don't have to download or install a OpenGL SDK. OpenGL is an API, there's an interfacing library shipped with the graphics drivers, and a link library and headers normally shipped with the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, I am aware that Windows Visual Studio only comes with OpenGL version 1.1. That is why I decided to use Glut, so that I could use functions from a later version of OpenGL such as 2.0.

GLUT will **not** help in this respect (or, I'm tempted to say, in any other respect either). What you're looking for is [GLEE](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/) or [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). Most implementations allow you to do this on your own as well; these libraries just make it easier -- but they do make it a *lot* easier.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL 2.x and earlier you just create a context.  That context must be backwards compatible with any version of OpenGL you care to use.  In OpenGL 3.0 and latter where strict API backwards compatibility was done away with there is a new method of context creation that allows you to specify the OpenGL version as attributes.